# Add Service Installer To Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

I am using Rider and .net Core and have created a worker service that I need to set-up as a windows service.  I'm at the point where I am ready to use `sc` to create everything but before I do I need to know how to set these parameters

```
this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "Description Test";
this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "Display Name Test";
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "Service1";
```

My current code reads like this

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureLogging(
        options => options.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Information))
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
            .Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
            {
                config.LogName = "Test";
                config.SourceName = "Test";
            });
    }).UseWindowsService();
```

Comment: I don't think `.UseWindowsService()` cares about how the service is installed / defined. But you should probably only call it once...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - I can update the code to only call it once, that's a good catch.  But how do I set the params that I want to like in my first code block?

Comment: Those service details are the responsibility of the installer, not the service. As I said, the default service implementation doesn't care what it is called.